# Recommend Share Point book for designing/theming

Tags: page-layout, theme, design

Hi I know there are a lot of sharepoint books out there, and I understand there may not be a book for exclusively for sharepoint design, but given that could anyone recommend a good book for someone whose main role as far as sharepoint is primarily themeing and layout.

Note: I am a professional web designer/developer, so I have experience writing a lot of front end code.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Trying to decide, most like 2013 - will be setting up in late spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a SharePoint version so here's a round-up of authors & books you can trust

*For SharePoint 2007 :*

**Professional SharePoint Design**
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-SharePoint-Design-Jacob-Sanford/dp/047028580X/ref=sr_1_45?ie=UTF8&qid=1363205063&sr=8-45](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047028580X)
This one was handy back in the 2007 era.

*For SharePoint 2010 :*

**Professional SharePoint 2010 Branding and User Interface Design** from Randy
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-SharePoint-Branding-Interface-Design/dp/0470584645/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1363204992&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470584645)

**SharePoint 2010 branding in practice: a guide for web developers** From Yaroslav
[http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2010-branding-practice-developers/dp/1460908732/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1363204993&sr=8-6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1460908732) (his latest book regarding SP2013 also tacke branding)

**Pro SharePoint Designer 2010** from Steve Wright 
[http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-Designer-2010-Professional-Apress/dp/1430236175/ref=sr_1_36?ie=UTF8&qid=1363205031&sr=8-36](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430236175)
(APress has some serious SharePoint books. Their Pro SP Search is still a marvel to read)

*For SharePoint 2013 :*

For SharePoint 2013, common branding techniques from 2010 mostly still applies but the new Design Manager / Theming engine / Channels mechanisms will bring a bunch of dedicated ebooks (watch out for the Randy one !)

Happy reading.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard good things about [Professional SharePoint Branding](http://www.walmart.com/ip/13847175?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227000000000&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=&wl3=21486607510&wl4=&wl5=pla&veh=sem)

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, I am hoping they will update for 2013.

Comment: Ya the 2013 versions should be coming out in the next few months but a lot of the same techniques still apply.